# Combining Flutter frontend with .NET Core backend for Android and iOS

Tags: c#, .net, dart, .net-core, flutter

Currently working for a company that use .NET (not Core) but want to switch to .NET Core and thought to do so by creating an app with a Flutter.io frontend and .NET Core backend. The app w/ backend is just to see how .NET Core functions.

I could not find any information if the combination of those two is even possible for Android/iOS.

I'm asking because Flutter has just been released into its beta stage.

Comment: This question as written is really a bit broad and/or unclear.  Assuming you want to use .NET (Core or not) for web API backend then it shouldn't matter.  If you mean something else you should clarify the question.

Comment: I should have mentioned that work wants to use WCF (SOAP) as backend. As far as I have found answers, there's no native support from Flutter in supporting SOAP, no?

Comment: Soap is still just http requests.  You won't get as much tooling as .NET but it still works

Answer (score 12, accepted):

.NET/core is for API, flutter is for native apps.
They are completely unrelated.

One side will have no impact on the other one. So yes, you can use both.

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/40719
this my issues between asp.core and flutter web

Comment: You can even build flutter for web apps: https://flutter.dev/web

Answer (score 8):

I  love using Flutter with my .Net Web Api  back ends. The web api support in Flutter is great as they have  built in  [JSON serialization support](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json). the combination is beautiful and  I am hooked on this powerful framework

Answer (score 4):

ServiceStack v5.1 has [added native support for Dart and Flutter](http://docs.servicestack.net/releases/v5.1.0#dart-and-flutter) where you can can generate an end-to-end Typed API from a remote URL, e.g:

```
$ dotnet tool install --global x

$ x dart https://techstacks.io
```

This is supported from .NET Core 2+ as well as any of [.NET's popular hosting options](http://docs.servicestack.net/why-servicestack#multiple-hosting-options). The example above generates a Typed API for the [.NET 6 TechStacks project](https://github.com/NetCoreApps/TechStacks).

The [HelloFlutter App](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/HelloFlutter) shows an example of calling a .NET Core and a classic ASP.NET App back-end using a Typed API:

[image: Hello Flutter App]

To call any Service you just need to import the [servicestack Dart package](https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/servicestack/0.0.8/client/client-library.html) and the generated DTOs, e.g:

```
import 'package:servicestack/client.dart';
import 'techstacks.dtos.dart';
```

Then create an instance of `JsonServiceClient` configured with your remote URL, e.g:

```
var client = new JsonServiceClient("https://www.techstacks.io");
```

Which you can then call within your Flutter widget like any async API:

```
class HelloFlutter extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => new HelloFlutterState();
}

class HelloFlutterState extends State<HelloFlutter> {
  //State for this widget
  String result = "";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

      //...
      new RaisedButton(
        child: new Text("Async"),
        onPressed: () async {
          var r = await client .get(new Hello(name: "Async"));
          setState(() {
            result = r.result;
          });
        },
      ),

      //...
      new Text(result),
  }
}
```

For more info see docs for [ServiceStack's native Dart support](http://docs.servicestack.net/dart-add-servicestack-reference).

Answer (score 1):

Probably, it's already a bit late to answer, but anyway I faced to the same question for my project.

This is clear, that Flutter and .net projects are separated from each other and can be connected v. REST API or gRPC but in my case I wanted really to merge them into one project to run from one director on my shared-hosting hosting and safe another domain name for front-end

Basically, the things are quite straightforward.

What I have:

- .net 6.0 WebAPI with RazorPages for some functions
- Flutter front-end talking to the WebAPI Back-End v. REST

There is a quick solution: use Static File in the .net project and copy the build of Flutter into Static Files directory (do not forget to delete line    from index.html of the Flutter Build.
The Downside - as it's a "static file", everyone can access all files of Flutter release build

So, I wanted to integrate it into .net as other .js libs and call it from "Pages" of the RazorPages

So, what I did:

- in the "Pages" of .net project created a folder "App" and added App.cshtml (w/o .cs in pair) with the folling content:

  ```
    @page
    @{
    }
    @section Scripts
    {
    <script>// The value below is injected by flutter build, do not touch.
        var serviceWorkerVersion = '947676792';</script>
    <!-- This script adds the flutter initialization JS code -->
    <script src="~/app/flutter.js" defer></script>

    <script>window.addEventListener('load', function (ev) {
            _flutter.loader.loadEntrypoint({
                serviceWorker: {
                    serviceWorkerVersion: serviceWorkerVersion,
                }
            }).then(function (engineInitializer) {
                return engineInitializer.initializeEngine();
            }).then(function (appRunner) {
                return appRunner.runApp();
            });
        });</script> 
        }
  ```

The script section is from index.html of the Flutter Web Build

- created flutter-special Layout file in .net (let's call it _AppLayout.cshtml) in the "Shared" Folder of the .net project with the following content:

  ```
  <html>
  <head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
  <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>`

      <base href="~/app/">

      <!--
        If you are serving your web app in a path other than the root, change the
        href value below to reflect the base path you are serving from.

        The path provided below has to start and end with a slash "/" in order for
        it to work correctly.

        For more details:
        * https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base

        This is a placeholder for base href that will be replaced by the value of
        the `--base-href` argument provided to `flutter build`.
      -->

      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta content="IE=Edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
      <meta name="description" content="A new Flutter project.">

      <!-- iOS meta tags & icons -->
      <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
      <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
      <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="web_flutter">
      <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="~app/icons/Icon-192.png">

      <!-- Favicon -->
      <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png" />

      <title>web_flutter</title>
      <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">

  </head>
  <body>

      @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)

  </body>
  </html>
  ```

This part was also taken from index.html of the Flutter Web Build with the modification of the `<base href="~/app/">` and adding @RenderSection to the body

- modified _ViewStart.cshtml from the Folder "Pages" of the .net project to use the template from above for Flutter Page

  ```
    @{
    var routeUrl = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Page"].ToString();
    //you can put pages' name into pages
    var pages = new List<string> { "/App/App" };
    //if routeUrl contains any of pages, the page will use _Layout as Layout page, the other pages will use _Layout1 ad Layout page
    if (!pages.Any(routeUrl.Contains))
    {
        Layout = "_Layout";
    }
    else
    {
        Layout = "_AppLayout";
    }
    }
  ```
- copied the Flutter app (web build as .js from build/web of the Flutter project) to the wwwroot/app directory of the .net project (you can name directory as you want, not necessary "app" but as you've spotted, I referenced to the "app" in all my code above)
- Add a link to my RazorPage App.cshtml to the Index.cshtml like
  `<a asp-page="/App/App">Flutter App</a>`

And that was it! Now I have a combination of Flutter and .net in one project and can deploy it as one directory!

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0):

I've also seen a project called Flutnet that uses the 2, but have not used it myself.

https://www.flutnet.com/

Answer (score 0):

They are independently.

I was Asp.Net MVC (razor page) then moved to Angular for UI. Now working with Flutter for UI.

I am doing the project you may find useful. `https://github.com/chhinsras/MiniStarter`