# What are options for Flutter App Backend?

Tags: api, rest, flutter, dart, architecture

Flutter is amazing but when your architecture needs the backend to be separate from the app. What are some options that will be good to consider?

Some options that I have looked at are: `Node.js`, `Java`, `Dart & Firebase` (Unsure whether Firebase can meet all the requirements as a **sole** backend of production-level apps)

We need to develop a full-fledged REST API which will be used in Production with the Flutter app.

Thank you

Comment: If it's going to be a simple app Firebase seems to be a viable option. If you need a relational db then going with .net core web api on Azure cloud seems a pretty good option.

Comment: What are the options?! Anything that can serve data. This question is too broad, too opinion-based, and essentially infinite.

Comment: You are absolutely correct @DaveNewton I am just looking for options.

Comment: @DaveNewton Okay, thanks Dave.

Answer (score 3):

It really depends how much time you have, and you're willing to spend on your backend. If you're rushed and want an MVP as soon as possible I would suggest FireBase, It provide great a simple but efficient database and more tools like instant messaging, built-in push.

If you have more time and want to build you're own features, Node.js with Express and Mongodb would be perfect.

Comment: I'd second that, if you got some time on your hands, go with Node, Express and MongoDB.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked into .NET Core Web Api? I have used on some projects on college together with MongoDb and works really well, I never try it with Flutter, but as a Api it works fine.

Edit: I just found this question, maybe it can help you [Combining Flutter frontend with .NET Core backend for Android and iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49114212/combining-flutter-frontend-with-net-core-backend-for-android-and-ios)